# Azure Data Factory: datetime conversion

Tags: timestamp, salesforce, azure-data-factory, timestamp-with-timezone, datetime-conversion

I have a pipeline with a copy activity with Salesforce as Sink and ADLS as source. I want the pipeline to copy only the records from Salesforce that are larger than the MAX(LastModifiedDate) from ADLS (Delta loads).

I have a control table in SQL which stores the lastupdated date for ADLS runs.When trying to run my pipeline I get the following error:

```
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorUnclassifiedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Odbc Operation Failed.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [22018] [Microsoft][Support] (40550) Invalid character value for cast specification.,Source=Microsoft Salesforce ODBC Driver,'
```

Before the copy activity I perform two lookups, 1 to retrieve the lastupdate date in my control table and 1 to retrieve the max value for LastModifiedDate in salesforce.

The values that are returned are as follows:

- ADLS/SQL `"ADLSWatermark": "2022-11-02T10:27:44.743Z"`
- Salesforce `"SalesforceWatermarkvalueDT": "2022-11-03T09:45:50Z"`

When configuring the copy activity for sink I connect to salesforce and run the following query (I am hardcoding the datetime values here for testing:
`SELECT * FROM Lead WHERE LastModifiedDate > '2022-11-02T10:27:44.743Z'`

This as a result throws the error provided above. When I update the timestamp in the where clause to this:

- `2022-11-02 10:27:44.743` 
  The copy activity runs without any issue.

For Sink I simply selected a folder in my ADLS container.

What I noticed is that both formats of date are different. Does anyone know how to make them equal? Or any other work around/solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use: `@{formatDateTime('2022-11-02T10:27:44.743Z','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

**formatDateTime** function is used to convert the datetime value into specified format.

Reference Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#formatDateTime